# Who was the first stretching comic book character?

Tags: comics, history-of

With Mr. Fantastic and Plastic Man as probably the best known examples, superhero comics have a diverse group of characters whose primary or exclusive power is to stretch their bodies into improbable shapes. The earliest example of such a character I'm able to find is [Thin Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Man_(comics)) from Marvel predecessor Timely Comics. Are there any older examples?

Comment: Earliest one I've found is also Thin Man.

Comment: @user14111 One of Jimmy Olsen's one-off superhero identities over the leader of The Fantastic Four? I'm a DC freak, and I forgot that was the name he took for that.

Comment: The FF is Silver Age, as is Elastic Lad.

Comment: @user14111 But does ideographic writing count as a comic book? If so, then ancient Egyptian mythology is in scope.

Comment: I meant comic books literally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The earliest "stretchy" superheroes seem to be **The Thin Man** and **Flexo the Rubber Man**, both of whom debuted in [Mystic Comics #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Comics_Vol_1_4) in **July, 1940**. Both superheroes (kinda) had stretching powers with The Thin Man capable of making himself thinner and Flexo (no, not [that one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo4Zl4g_4x4)) capable of using his flexible rubber shell to twist and rotate at high speeds.

[image]

[image]

The first superhero capable of actually *stretching themselves into other forms* appears to be Plastic Man who debuted in [Police Comics #1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Police_Comics_Vol_1_1) in **August, 1941**

[image]

Followed by other heroes like **Elastic Lad** (Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen #31 -  Feb, 1958) and **Mr. Fantastic** (The Fantastic Four #1 - Nov, 1961)

You may wish to note that the concept of a *stretching character* dramatically pre-dates Western comic books, with traditional Japanese [rokurokubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokurokubi) (from the 1600s) depicted in storybooks as having stretchy and detachable necks.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Also of note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_Man

Comment: I don't understand the "In memory of..." image. Can you provide some context?

Comment: @Gaultheria - Stretchie Boy was a character from the hit film [*The Specials*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wMvv924Gks). He's mentioned (as having stretching powers) but not seen other than in this still image.